# pdf file delete not working in php codeigniter using unlink

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to delete my pdf file from server. my controller function looks like

```
function delete_pdf()
{
  $id = (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']!='')?$_GET['id']:'1';  
  $user_email = $this->session->userdata('user_email');
  $file = site_url('pdf files/'.$user_email.'/pdf #'. $id.'.pdf');
  unlink($file);
}
```

when i `echo $file;`, it gives url `http://localhost/my_site/pdf files/developer_team@gmail.com/pdf #4.pdf` but the function not working to delete the pdf file.

I would appreciate for any help where i can delete my pdf files from server. thank you.

Comment: `unlink` requires an absolute path and not a URL.

Comment: try with realpath function of php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can't delete file using URL. we  need absolute path. try this-:
 `$file = FCPATH.'pdf files/'.$user_email.'/pdf #'. $id.'.pdf';`

Answer (score 0):

try to remove space in pdf #4.pdf in your url

```
http://localhost/my_site/pdf files/developer_team@gmail.com/pdf #4.pdf
```

Comment: You can't unlik file via http url, You need file system path in server

Answer (score 0):

You need the absolute path to the file, I mean something like this

`/Users/me/..../my_sites/pdf`
The path depends of where is your controller. I don't know how codeigniter works.

**EDIT**

```
$file = dirname(__FILE__). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'..'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'..'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'pdf files/'.$user_email.'/pdf #'. $id.'.pdf';
```

It will give you this :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\my_site\application\controllers\..\..\pdf files\developer_team@gmail.com\pdf #4.pdf
```

Comment: hi `@LolWalid` thank you for your suggestion. in codeigniter, `dirname(__FILE__)` not giving the required file location. it's giving file path as `C:\xampp\htdocs\my_site\application\controllers/pdf files/developer_team@gmail.com/pdf #4.pdf`.

Comment: That's the path you need to unlink the file. Look my edit it should work now.